# Refining parent object by type guard on property only

Tags: typescript

I have a type `Box<T>` where `T` will always be something that extends a `State` which is a discriminated union.

```js
type StateA = { type: "A"; a: number };
type StateB = { type: "B"; b: string };
type State = StateA | StateB;

interface Box<T extends State = State> {
  state: T;
}
```

I would now like to inspect what kind of `Box` a variable is and narrow the type argument to that more specific type. The naive approach of checking the type of the discriminated union sort of works. The usual type inference using `if` or `switch` statements works fine when immediately accessing properties of the boxed state. But the type of the `Box` doesn't narrow, only the type of `Box.state`.

```js
const b: Box = { state: { type: "B", b: "str" } };
if (b.state.type === "B") {
  console.log(b.state.b); // Inferred correctly
  const bRefined: Box<StateB> = b; // Assignment not possible
}
```

This can be worked around with a user defined type guard though:

```js
function isBoxB(b: Box): b is Box<StateB> {
  return b.state.type === "B";
}

if (isBoxB(b)) {
  console.log(b.state.b); // Inferred correctly
  const bRefined: Box<StateB> = b; // Assignment possible
}
```

I can live with that workaround, but I am not exactly happy with it. Is there any better way to automatically narrow the type of the surrounding `Box` without writing custom type guards?

[The whole code is available on the Typescript Playground.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAysCGwIEEoF4oG8qkgLigCJlCBuKeAgOwFcBbAIwgCcoBfUgKF2jkQgBC6LDnAQChAWSgMCAZ2DMAllQDm7Lj1gIkwvklQAfbfwFdOKpMwBm8AMbQBAewAeAHgAqUCC6RUAJnImuhj6EAB8WJxQUAr8BB5cbJycdk5UCjIEzi7C2HFIBNg8ElIANFlECsyE7BoW1lAAFAwAdAUQrVpoPURSAJRRMWkZTgA2nWNOqi3tOp0M-eQA9MtQAJJU1izMEP5Qacy7dsBjINEH6ZkMAEoQ1ip72a5uYQKRGAwra8hyckqqKh0CBUYBQKhOMFgJx-JQMCacZKcaw0KgnJTpKBKOQ5AQtZ4ufoEBhYoI5V7zd5DKC7YA0ZhUGRzfhdMToXqSMiIlINZrY3EtfqDTAXEZycaTaazDqtRbfDZbHZ7S5HCAnM6iq5g273R7%20AkU0wfGTy37-QHA0FQaGw%20EQbmcIA)

Comment: This is currently a TS design limitation; property checks do not narrow parent objects unless that parent object's type is a discriminated union, and `Box` is not a union at all.  The current open issue about this is [ms/TS#42384](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42384).  For now, unless you walk the compiler through the logic by copying the checked property like [this](https://tsplay.dev/Nl2ERW), you'll need some kind of custom type guard.  There are more general ones like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wRXGxm), but they're still extra work.

Comment: Does that fully address your question? If so I could write up an answer.  If not, what am I missing?

Comment: That answers my question, feel free to "convert" it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In TypeScript, [narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) the apparent type of an object's property (or subproperty, or sub-subproperty, etc) does not narrow the apparent type of the object itself, in general.  The only time this does happen is if the object is of a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) type and the property you're checking is its *discriminant*.

In your case, although the `state` property of `Box` is of the discriminated union type `State`, `Box` itself is not a discriminated union.  It's not a union at all. So if you have a value `b` of type `Box`, then even though checking `b.state.type` will narrow `b.state`, it will not narrow `b` itself.

This is a known limitation of TypeScript, and has been reported multiple times.  The currently-open issue asking for improvement here is [microsoft/TypeScript#42384](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42384). In the past, these were just closed as being too expensive to fix (in order for a check of `a.b.c.d.e` to narrow more than just `a.b.c.d.e`, the compiler might need to synthesize new types to represent the effects on  `a.b.c.d`, `a.b.c`, `a.b`, and `a`).  A [comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42384#issuecomment-763048323) suggests that maybe the situation has evolved and it *is* possible to implement. But for now it's not implemented.

Until and unless this changes, we just have to work around it.

---

One workaround which sometimes works for people is to copy the existing object into a new object where the checked property is singled out for copying explicitly.  This walks the compiler through the logic of synthesizing the narrowed type.  In your case it looks like this:

```
if (b.state.type === "B") {
  const bRefined: Box<StateB> = { ...b, state: b.state } // okay
}
```

Here we've [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals) the existing `b` object into a new object literal, and then explicitly copied the `state` property over.  Now the compiler sees that `{...b, state: b.state}` is of type `Box<StateB>`.

---

Otherwise, the general workaround is to build a [custom type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) which encapsulates the concept of "a check of a property should narrow the parent".  It could look like this:

```
function hasPropType<T extends object, K extends keyof T, V extends T[K]>(
  obj: T, key: K, valGuard: (x: T[K]) => x is V): obj is T & Record<K, V> {
  return valGuard(obj[key]);
}
```

This tells the compiler that if `valGard(obj[key])` is `true`, then `hasPropType(obj, key, valGuard)` can narrow the type of `obj`.  In your example it could look like this:

```
if (hasPropType(b, "state", (x): x is StateB => x.type === "B")) {
  const bRefined: Box<StateB> = b; // okay
}
```

Of course for a single usage this is more complicated than just using your `isBoxB()` method.  But if you find yourself doing such checks a lot, you might not need to build individual type guard functions for each check.

---

A compromise here might be to write a slightly more general type guard than `isBoxB` but less general than `hasPropType`:

```
function isBox<K extends State['type']>(type: K, b: Box
): b is Box<Extract<State, { type: K }>> {
  return b.state.type === type;
}

if (isBox("B", b)) {
  const bRefined: Box<StateB> = b; // okay
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAysCGwIEEoF4oG8qkgLigCJlCBuKeAgOwFcBbAIwgCcoBfUgKF2jkQgBC6LDnAQChAWSgMCAZ2DMAllQDm7Lj1gIkwvklQAfbfwFdOKpMwBm8AMbQBAewAeAHgAqUCC6RUAJnImuhj6EAB8WJxQUAr8BB5cbJwpdk5UCjIEzi7C2HFIBNg8ElIANFlECsyE7BopStZQABQMAHQFEG1aaL1EUgCUUTFpGcAyAEoQ1ioQ-tmubmECkRjYbRsMFZ0E7Z11APQHUE4A1vAgnMmc1jRUdsBK6VAAFvByAArMTmAeYp7eXwQAJBJwMABWEAeFQA0oC-IEoKcICAnE0PBUAGrw4GIjwAbRhAF1ws1oicIQkKsiQAQYRUAG7wAA2AHEaPBmPMWi4EoSiUM0JFckogpiBgQweCoKKoF4AGRQKZpLluelQTGRTDk5gQYA0ZhUKBMtkcrnNKX4mkCpINJrNN6fb6-MStCqETqECrNFwSqAioLLdDC7pidB9SSEAZDbUjdKZBhTGZUOYLdzLVYychHE7nS7XW73R7PUU5NU4kHBCD4gDkPBrJOaJSg6tkUBynD9DBlQTLAFFfMx7MAljoIBVimI6exwlqdXqDUa9mPQ5BwxgeLaLPbS65mpGKgxo8MoKME0nZtyyxnhAxs8czhcrilOEA)

Comment: Is there a point where all these little workarounds that require extra code (and operations) to satisfy TypeScript actually create a meaningful performance difference? Just something in the back of my mind when I do this and know my code is going to be 0.002 milliseconds slower.

Comment: Performance at runtime?  I'd hope any reasonable runtime engine would optimize/inline any function that gets run often enough to matter.  Compiler performance?  Not sure

Comment: Just to have mentioned this: I wen't with the `isBox` function you proposed. This is really a beautiful sweet spot between "too magic" and "not annoying".